# How to store user entered record in a file using structure in c?

Tags: c, file, structure, store, record

How to store user entered record in a file using structure in c?
i made the structure and also wrote the code for opening file and used fprintf to save that record in that file but that file is storing other things rather than what i have entered to store.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and [edit] your question to show it, together with a description of the problems you have.

Comment: please add your code to the post.